# Why was there a courtroom in the Department of Mysteries?

Tags: harry-potter

This question comes from Chapter 7 of the Order of the Phoenix.

> “No, no, it’s not the toilet, it’s the Potter boy’s hearing — they’ve changed the time and venue — it starts at eight o’clock now and it’s down in old Courtroom Ten —”
>
> “Down in old — but they told me — Merlin’s beard —”

I guess Fudge wanted to make the hearing as intimidating as possible for Harry, so this question isn't really about that. From what we know about the Department of Mysteries it seems quite an unlikely place to have a courtroom, whether old or current. The Department of Mysteries is a place where learned wizarding scientists study all aspect of magic at it's deepest and so on. So why have a courtroom there to prosecute alleged crimes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Harry's hearing was actually held in a level further down from the Department of Mysteries. The elevator lets Harry and Mr. Weasley off at the Department of Mysteries, yes, but they then take a flight of stairs down to the courtroom. So, technically, the hearing was not held in the Department of Mysteries.

> ‘Quick, Harry,’ said Mr Weasley as the lift doors rattled open, and they sped up a corridor that was quite different from those above. The walls were bare; there were no windows and no doors apart from a plain black one set at the very end of the corridor.
>   Harry expected them to go through it, but instead Mr Weasley seized him by the arm and dragged him to the left, where there was an opening leading to a flight of steps.
>   ‘Down here, down here,’ panted Mr Weasley, taking two steps at a time. ‘The lift doesn’t even come down this far ... why they’re doing it down there I ...’
>   <sub>*Order of the Phoenix* - page 124 - Chapter seven, *The Ministry of Magic* - Bloomsbury</sub>

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you. I guess I missed that on all my rereads. Now it makes perfect sense. Such a quick resolution.

Comment: @MermishEssence -It's one of the main benefits of having direct access to JKR. She can often answer these questions without having to go hunting for references.